# Solidity & Truffle - Automatic test case generate in Solidity and JavaScript, What is the best option? Props and Cons?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, solidity, truffle, vyper

I created new ERC-20 token and now, want to add test code.
Is there any ways to auto-generate test-cases in SOL files?
And also want to know the way of auto generate test code in Truffle JavaScript framework.

I already googled and got some useful libraries but it's not auto generated code. (Like **mocha** or **chai**)
Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the brownie test framework for testing Vyper smart contracts.
And it can be used for testing solidity smart contracts, too.
Refer to this repository.
https://github.com/webelf101/curve-volumegauge